# Converting list of bytes to a normal string with Python

Tags: python, encode

I'm having trouble converting a list of bytes to string.
Whenever I apply:

```
char = chr(int(byte,2))
```

I get the right character, but when I concatenate it with a string:

```
string+= char
```

I get weird symbols:

```
÷ãÐªþãÝ¿HÛaû³ªI|ÁŸì½ XG„8jRTa!qÚhÏ¹4ý{B
```

After Googling, I found out that I have to convert it to UTF-8 using `string.encode('utf-8')`, but after converting it, I get something like this:

```
b'string'
```

I couldn't find a way to remove the `b''` from the output

```
string=""
for byte in bytes:
    char = chr(int(byte,2))
    string+=char

print(string.encode('utf-8'))
#output : b'my string'

print(string)
#output :  ÷ãÐªþãÝ¿HÛaû³ªI|ÁŸì½ XG„8jRTa!qÚhÏ.....
```

I'm looking for a way to convert my bytes to a normal string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert bytes to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

Comment: @LucG thanks for answering, unfortunately, i read the post before and i reviewed it again now, the list i have contains bytes, after converting them to chars, then concatenate them in a string, i use encode and then i get the b'string' output, if i use decode again on them (as mentioned in the post) i will get those weird symbols again. even converting the byte list to ints and then `"".join(map(chr, bytes_data))` will give me the same weird symbols too.

Comment: after trying to solve it again, i tried to run it with cmd (i was using pycharm), with cmd it gives me the right output, but pycharm it gives me wrong output